# NodeJS Express Server Failing to Launch on CPanel

Tags: node.js, npm, cpanel

I'm trying to upload my NodeJS express server to cdnapi.club through CPanel, It is using v16.17.1 and has DiscordJS, Express.

This is the error I am currently getting

```
Listening on port 3000
stderr:
/home/cdncraft/nodevenv/cdnapi.club/16/lib/node_modules/undici/lib/client.js:1184
        if (socket[kParser].timeoutType !== TIMEOUT_IDLE) {
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'timeoutType')
    at _resume (/home/cdncraft/nodevenv/cdnapi.club/16/lib/node_modules/undici/lib/client.js:1184:29)
    at resume (/home/cdncraft/nodevenv/cdnapi.club/16/lib/node_modules/undici/lib/client.js:1148:3)
    at connect (/home/cdncraft/nodevenv/cdnapi.club/16/lib/node_modules/undici/lib/client.js:1133:3)
```

It starts listening to the actual port and then it crashes for some reason. I have been looking and trying to fix things for hours and haven't seen a fix. This is the index.js file for starting the server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = 3000
app.set('port', port)

const v1_path = "/api/v1"

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
  })

app.get(`/`, (request, response) => {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/pages/index.html')
})
```

This is the package.json https://pastes.dev/aUcTtdU0vX

Comment: Looks like your socket connection is getting lost, i.e., a potential network issue. Have you retried it? And, there are better ways to upload to CPanel.

Comment: What are the better ways to upload? I created it through the Node.js section on CPanel. Im unsure why it is failing to start.